# If I need to check if all instances of a tuple are true and return the values of those that are how should I start?

Tags: sql

The question asks me to find all the managers at this specific company  that have been employed more recently than ALL of their more subordinate staff.
st_name is the persons name, 
st_hiredate is when they were hired and 
st_possition is if they are a manager, assistant or supervisor.

When I run the query below I correctly get all the tuples I need to make the comparison but I can't run it to produce tuples of all managers that were hired after ALL of their junior staff.

Is there a condition that I can use that says if all instances of a staff member's name is not the same as all instances of their hire date being before their junior staff then don't return their name?

```
SELECT a.st_name, a.st_hiredate, b.st_name, b.st_hiredate
FROM (SELECT st_name, st_hiredate, st_position FROM staff WHERE st_position = 'assistant' OR st_position = 'Supervisor') as b JOIN (SELECT st_name, st_hiredate, st_position FROM staff WHERE st_position = 'manager') as a;
```

There are 17 staff 6 of which are managers and 11 of which are not. When I run the above query it brings back 66 tuples which means that I am accurately comparing each manager against each of their subordinates. Now how to I state that it must be greater than every other subordinate staff member?

Comment: How do you know who is the manager for a given staff member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this kind of query
not exactly sure of syntax.just get the idea.

```
SELECT * FROM Staff
WHERE st_position='manager'
AND
st_hireDate >(SELECT max(st_hireDate) FROM 
Staff WHERE st_position='Supervisor' OR st_position='assistant' )
```

Comment: @RyanSeanWattrus you can add some test data and test whether its right.Its a pleasure helping you

Comment: I changed some values in my table to test it and it worked! Thank you so much! A simple solution to something I was making far to complicated.